# Mounting a set of fully-encrypted drives with a single password prompt upon booting

Tags: hard-drive, encryption, bitlocker, veracrypt, diskcryptor

I have a laptop with a single OS installed on SSD (`C:\`, Windows 10 Pro + programs and apps, no multiboot, no GPT), secondary HDD (`D:\`, my files and libraries) and an external USB-HDD (`E:\`, for backups only).

I would like to set up a full-disk encryption on all three drives so that:

1. The password is the same for all drives and is to be entered *only once* upon booting (not counting Windows logon screen, of course), which results in automatic mounting of all drives before Windows starts;
2. If Windows 10 fails to boot, the content of all the drives should be easily accessible (e.g. one should be able to decrypt them) from another computer or from  Linux LiveCD/LiveUSB;
3. No wiping is required.

I used to use [DiskCryptor](https://diskcryptor.net/wiki/Main_Page) for this and it worked fairly good for parts 1 and 3, but I could't figure out how to get access to the files from a Linux pendrive once, when the only things a had were the computer with a Windows refusing to boot and a LiveUSB drive with Linux, and I needed my files ASAP.

For the same reason it seems like going with a built-in BitLocker is also not an option. [Veracrypt](https://www.veracrypt.fr/en/Home.html), on the other hand, would assure parts 2 and 3, but I cannot figure out how to mount a *set* of drives at once alongside with a system partition.

Is there something I'm missing, and what's the best way to mount several encrypted drives at once?

I apologize in advance if the question seems to be too broad or off-topic here. I'm not an expert in computer security and I tried to solve this problem for myself for a while without 100% of success.

Comment: Is requirement #4 to be free? There are commercial products to do this. The other suggestion would be to look in to using a laptop with a TPM hardware module. With TPM you don’t need passwords.

Comment: Free is of course better, but I'd trade freedom for convenience and accesibility here (shame on me, I know, but I use Windows after all:) ). Unfortunately, I have a rather old Thinkpad with an obsolete CPU which doesn't have a TPM module.